# How to assign a shortcut key/macro for TODO notes in TexStudio?

Tags: texstudio, todonotes

I need to write a lot of `%todo` notes inside TexStudio, so I need a shortcut to do so. I thought of assigning a macro but I couldn't, because as soon as I enter `%` the radio button of type inside the macro window switches automatically from *normal* to *environment* giving the undesired effect (see below), am I missing something? What would be the right way to make this shortcut at disposal?

**Note**
TeXstudio 2.7.0 - Windows 7.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid the "%%" issue in macro creation:

1. Go to make a macro as you normally would
2. Switch to the **Script** type
3. Write a script using editor commands:
4. Link the new macro to your keyboard shortcut

[image: Macro script to]

```
%SCRIPT
editor.insertText("%TODO: ")
```

Comment: the best workaround!

Answer (score 1):

Use two `%%`. The you can see the macro on Macro menu. Shortcut to it in my case is Shift+F1.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: no success, as I said, as soon as I type `%` inside the box the radio button will jump to environment. I use TeXstudio 2.7.0, win7.

Comment: Even if you type two consecutive? When I typed the first one the radio button goes to *Environment* and after I typed the second one it comes back to *Normal*. But I'm using Linux.

Comment: in my case, it starts with *normal*, as I type the first `%`, it jumps to *environment*, by second `%` it remains.

Comment: as a workaround I typed a space first, then it won't jump, i.e., ` %todo`, suboptimal, but better than no shortcut.